# Routing an image through GroupMe's image service with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, groupme

I'm using `requests` to make a POST request to GroupMe's image service that should return a URL of the hosted image that I can use to post to a GroupMe thread. The [documentation](https://dev.groupme.com/docs/image_service) mentions that I need my access token and the binary image data in the payload in order to do this.

Here is a very simple example of how my code to do this currently looks:

```
import requests

access_token = 'my_access_token'
img_path = 'picture_name.jpg'

img_service_url = 'https://image.groupme.com/pictures'

r = requests.post(img_service_url, files={'file': img_path})
```

**EDIT:**

I looked at the documentation and source for the `groupy.api.endpoint` module `Groupy`(https://groupy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.2/_modules/groupy/api/endpoint.html#Images) and updated my script (reflected above) to use the same `requests` function parameters, but to no avail. Now the code returns a `500`.

Comment: Not sure, but the documentation calls the token with "X-Access-Token:" instead of access_token ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me (avatar.jpeg is in the same folder as my testing.py code below)

```
# curl 'https://image.groupme.com/pictures'
# -X POST
# -H "X-Access-Token: $GM_TOKEN"
# -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg"
# --data-binary @AwesomePicture.jpg

import requests

data = open('./avatar.jpeg', 'rb').read()
res = requests.post(url='https://image.groupme.com/pictures',
                    data=data,
                    headers={'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
                             'X-Access-Token': 'ACCESS_TOKEN'})
print(res.content)
```

OUTPUT

```
b'{"payload":{"url":"https://i.groupme.com/100x100.jpeg.5b71f15633f6454ca6a3a6b3e267a3fb","picture_url":"https://i.groupme.com/100x100.jpeg.5b71f15633f6454ca6a3a6b3e267a3fb"}}\n'
```

Comment: Is there a particular example/resource that you used in order to figure out the exact payload needed for this HTTP request?

Comment: I signed up for the API, I looked at the API documentation link you specified, I Googled "curl to requests in python" and grabbed an example, and converted that example to match the API. I had Pycharms already installed to run Python code because I was helping someone else with their python code.